# Вытащить структуру из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть БД mysql и драйвер PDO.
Мне нужно вытащить всю структуру, в том числе и внешние ключи. Как можно вытащить все внешние ключи не обращаясь к `information_schema`?

К примеру у меня есть информация об индексе:

```
object(stdClass)#14 (13) {
    ["Table"]=>
    string(4) "table_name"
    ["Non_unique"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Key_name"]=>
    string(9) "action_id"
    ["Seq_in_index"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Column_name"]=>
    string(9) "action_id"
    ["Collation"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["Cardinality"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["Sub_part"]=>
    NULL
    ["Packed"]=>
    NULL
    ["Null"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Index_type"]=>
    string(5) "BTREE"
    ["Comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Index_comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
```

Как узнать на какую таблицу и на какой столбец он ссылается?

Answer (score 2):

без `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` - никак. Только распарсить вывод `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, что, впрочем, не такая уж сложная задача.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

`mysql> show create table child\G`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: child
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `par_ind` (`parent_id`),
  #вытаскиваем REFERENCES `parent` (`id`) регуляркой, или, если есть, SQL-парсером
  CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Внешний ключ почти никогда не реализуется в виде жесткой связи, связь эта всегда умозрительная. Да, есть ограничение внешнего ключа `FOREIGN KEY` - однако, это в первую очередь ограничение, не связь.

Поле `action_id` может ссылаться на таблицу `actions` или на таблицу `versions` или на любую другую таблицу, как вы сами того пожелаете. Связываете же вы таблицы либо в многотабличных SELECT-запросах, либо внутри вашего приложения.

Именно поэтому для база данных рисуют ERP-диаграммы, чтобы отразить эти связи, которые в схему не зашиты. Да ключи есть, однако связи появляются только в SELECT-запросах, не в схеме.

Comment: вы на какой вопрос отвечаете?

Comment: Нельзя в общем случае узнать на какую таблицу ссылается внешний ключ. Вопрос самый последний в конце сообщения.